# How to fix wrong node version in `firebase deploy --only functions`

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When i run `firebase deploy --only functions`, it responds with an error about node version incompatibility.  My system has node 20.11.0 and firebase 13.1.0 installed (managed with `asdf`).

In package.json, `"engines": { "node": ">=18.5" }` is specified, and `"runtime": "nodejs20"` is specified in firebase.json.

There is a dependency on sharp which requires node `^18.17.0 || ^20.3.0 || >=21.0.0`.

`firebase deploy --only functions` gets past lint and other steps, but finally fails, complaining about finding `node 18.5.0` (which isn’t on my system at all) and requiring at least `18.7.0` due to sharp.

I'd like the whole thing to run using node 20.3.0, but can't figure out how to make that happen.

Here’s the actual output:

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase typescript for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase typescript to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8928

Error: Could not load the "sharp" module using the darwin-x64 runtime
Possible solutions:
- Please upgrade Node.js:
    Found 18.5.0
    Requires ^18.17.0 || ^20.3.0 || >=21.0.0
- Consult the installation documentation:
    See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/troy/Projects/field-tracker-admin-console/functions/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:114:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1890:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1851:31)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/troy/Projects/field-tracker-admin-console/functions/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:10:1)


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

Comment: If you're suggesting that the CLI is doing the wrong thing with `"runtime": "nodejs20"`, then you should file a bug on [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) and provide a minimal repro example.  There's not much the volunteers of Stack Overflow can do to fix this other than debug the CLI, submit a PR, and wait for Firebase to accept it and release a new version.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the purpose of "runtime" is to determine the node version during the build process .  I haven't been able to find clear documentation on that.  If that is the case, I agree.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_nodejs_version

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for that.  I read that, but I thought the runtime meant in the cloud, not locally.  I see that the complaint in the output is referencing the darwin-x64 runtime, which is a mac thing, which is my development environment.  I don't understand why that is coming into play when deploying to the cloud.

Comment: I'm not clear why you chose to specify `"engines": { "node": ">=18.5" }` when you don't have it and you'd rather 20.

Comment: I'm trying everything I can think of to get the `Found 18.5.0` issue resolved.  Is that the local environment saying that, or something in the cloud?  I can't figure out where 18.5.0 coming from.  Node is not one of my native languages ;).  I see in the documentation thet "runtime" overrides "engines", and I've tried it without that as well.

Comment: You said that your package.json specifies `"engines": { "node": ">=18.5" }`.  Why?  If it's not necessary, can you just change it to 20?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256721/discussion-between-troy-and-doug-stevenson).

Answer (score 1):

I took a deep dive into nodejs, npm, and a side trip through yarn to figure this out.

The fundamental issue was that I needed a specific node version and using the globally installed firebase would not support me.  I learned that firebase-tools has a specific nodejs version built in so that it can be standalone and not a pain for most cases.  But in my case, I needed a slightly newer node version than was in the latest firebase-tools.  It seems firebase-tools version 13.1.0 has node 18.5.0 built in, but I needed at least 18.7.0 for my dependencies.  I ended up using nodejs 20.11.0.

It seemed like `"runtime": "nodejs20"` in `firebase.json` would do the trick, but it did not.  I don't know enough about the situation to say it's a bug in firebase-tools, nodejs, or npm or if I'm just missing something.

***Anyhow, here's how I resolved it:***

With firebase-tools installed globally, the `firebase` command uses its packaged node version when deploying functions.

To use a specific version of node, install `firebase-tools` via `npm` and then execute it from the local (non packaged) nodejs.

Step by step:

1. Optionally install `asdf` to manage the versions of nodejs and other tools used in various projects
2. Install the needed version of `nodejs` - here's how with asdf:

   ```
   cd <project root>
   asdf add plugin nodejs
   asdf install nodejs 20.11.0
   asdf local nodejs 20.11.0
   ```
3. In the project's functions directory, use asdf again to use the same version of `node`

   ```
   asdf local nodejs 20.11.0
   ```
4. In the project's root, use `npm` to install firebase-tools

   ```
   npm install firebase-tools
   ```
5. Update `firebase.json` and `functions/package.json` to reference the node version

   **firebase.json**

   ```
   "functions": [
     {
       "runtime":"nodejs20",
       <- snip ->
     }]
   ```

   **functions/package.json**

   ```
   "engine":{"node":">=20"},
   ```
6. In the project's root, add some convenience scripts to `package.json` to have it launch the local firebase in the local nodejs version:

   **package.json**

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "firebase": "firebase",
     "df": "firebase deploy --only functions",
     < add more here as needed >
   }
   ```

   Those "scripts" have `node_modules/.bin` in their path, so, for example, the `firebase` script runs `node_modules/.bin/firebase` in the local nodejs.

   I added the `df` script because I kept forgetting to add the double dashes to make --only functions work.  Without those extra double dashes, the switch applies to npm in stead of firebase.

   Here's how to run those scripts in the project root:

   ```
   % npm run df # same as `npm run -- firebase deploy --only functions`
   % npm run firebase -V # check the version
   ```
7. I think that's it - all the usual `firebase` commands now work using `npm run -- firebase ...`.  Add scripts as you see fit to make it easier to type them correctly.

Thanks go to @DougStevenson for prodding me in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, have not been able to find any answer elsewhere as to why I am not allowed to use NodeJS 20 as the engine for Firebase Functions even though version 20 is supported as (preview) according the documentation. But this was a great breakdown of the issue.